# Error when converting date string to NSObject

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm sending details to a server which requires that I convert a date string into an NSDate object. The dictionary that will carry this object is declared like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *detailsRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Then the code which converts the date string to an object looks like this

```
[_dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
[_dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@"am"];
[_dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@"pm"];
[detailsRequest setObject:[_dateFormatter stringFromDate:[_dateFormatter dateFromString:val]] forKey:NDUserServerDateOfBirthKey];
```

The key NDUserServerDateOfBirthKey is declared as a constant like this

```
NSString * const NDUserServerDateOfBirthKey     = @"dob";
```

The value for val is always '09/08/1987' and when it hits the last line it throws a SIGABRT error which says

```
2018-08-23 10:33:04.612769+0100 ClientCore[353:36543] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: dob)'
```

I've tried reducing the _dateFormatter to just [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; but it still crashes with the same error. My string date always has a value so what is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `[_dateFormatter dateFromString:val]` is nil. Now, the question is what is `val`? Is not related at all to `NSDictionary` nor `NSObject` nor `XCode`, I'll change the tags. That's a basic `NSDateFormatter` issue. As you this: How `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"` should match `"09/08/1987"`? It can't. The `dateFormat` should be `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` depending if the first one is the month or the day of the month.

Comment: With the stringFromDate method you aren't converting a NSString to a NSDate but a NSDate to a NSString

Comment: Moreover, what do you mean by "date string" and "NSObject"? Any object inherits from NSObject, and there's no such object as a "date string" - it is either a NSDate or a NSString - can you please clarify what you need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the date format is wrong and the date string cannot be converted.

Please try to understand the format. The date string contains day (d), month (M) and year (y) slash separated – or month (M), day (d) and year (y) - but there is no letter `T`, no hyphens (-), no hours (H), no minutes (m), no seconds (s), no milliseconds (S), no timezone (Z) and no am/pm

The format is `@"dd/MM/yyyy"` or `@"MM/dd/yyyy"`

And why are you converting string to date and then immediately back to string?

If you want to convert `dd/MM/yyyy` to ISO8601 you need two different formats for input and output

```
NSString *val = @"09/08/1987";
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
_dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
_dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";
NSDate *date = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:val];
_dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ";
NSString *convertedString = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: It may have worked, but it would be good if you knew what you are doing, because it looks like, as mentioned by @vadian, you're moving back and forth stuff and converting more than you need